# Cannot find name "T" Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Why I get this error message:

```
Cannot find name "T"
```

Code:

```
const List: React.FC<T> = ({ items, render }: {
  items: T[];
  render: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      { items.map((el ,i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{el}</Text>
      )) }
    </View>
  )
}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Assuming you are trying to make it a type parameter of the function, it should be `const List: React.FC = <T>(...)`.

Comment: This not working I get unexcepted token error

Comment: Oh, it needs to be `<T,>(...)` to avoid ambiguity in the syntax when Typescript generics are mixed with JSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic that `React.FC` accepts is used to type the props object. So instead of inline typing your props, you would create an interface that accepts its own generic:

```
interface ListProps<T = unknown> {
  items: T[];
  render: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

and then declare the interface that you will pass into the `ListProps` generic:

```
interface YourGenericType {
  el: string;
}
```

To consume these two interfaces together with your component:

```
const List: React.FC<ListProps<YourGenericType>> = ({ items, render }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {items.map((el, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{el}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Edit:** I would also add that unless you need access to an implicit `children` type, it's recommended that you don't use `React.FC` as a function type signature. [See here for more info](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177). With this in mind, I would type your List component like so:

```
const List = ({ items, render }: ListProps<YourGenericType>) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {items.map((el, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{el}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```